# Specify RPM build order in mock

Tags: postgresql, mocking, rpm, postgresql-11, fedora-27

**TLDR: Ensure to keep system OS up-to-date to help ensure consistency with current spec files.**

**Symptom**

When rebuilding PostgreSQL 11.1 SRPM using `mock`, the build fails with:

```
BUILDSTDERR: /builddir/build/BUILD/postgresql-11.1/src/bin/psql/command.c:1814 undefined reference to `PQencryptPasswordConn`
```

**NB**: `PQencryptPasswordConn` is a `libpq.so` function (provided by `postgresql-devel-10.3-5.fc27.x86_64` on my system...outside the mock chroot environment). Unless I'm mistaken, the Postgresql SRPM builds the `postgresql-devel` RPM along with others.

**Steps to reproduce**

I ran the following to rebuild the SRPM *before* attempting to apply any patches not already present in the SRPM:

```
# Obtain SRPM source
git clone https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/postgresql.git
cd postgresql

# Download local copies of SRPM sources
wget $(spectool -S *.spec | awk '/^Source.*:\/\//{IFS=" "; print $2}')
# ...check SHAs of downloaded sources...

# Run SRPM-specific prep scripts
./generate-pdf.sh
./generate-sources.sh

# Generate the SRPM
mock --root=fedora-27-x86_64 --resultdir="./SRPMS" --buildsrpm --spec postgresql.spec --sources .

# >>> Everything seems to work fine up to this point <<<

# Build the RPM inside mock chroot
mock --root=fedora-27-x86_64 --rebuild ./SRPMS/postgresql-11.1-4.fc27.src.rpm

# !!! Fail here (with symptom above) !!!
```

**The Problem**

I have so far been unable to have `mock` load the appropriate `libpq` library headers into the chroot environment to make sure `rpmbuild` builds against the `libpq` that contains the `PQencryptPasswordConn` header (which appears to exist on my system outside the build environment):

```
grep -lr "PQencryptPasswordConn" /usr/include
# /usr/include/libpq-fe.h

grep -lr "PQencryptPasswordConn" /var/lib/mock/fedora-27-x86_64/root/usr/include
# (Nothing returned)
```

When reviewing `mock`'s `installed_pkgs.log`, the following were installed (the latter of which I expect would provide a version of `libpq` headers):

```
postgresql-libs-9.6.10-3.fc27.x86_64
postgresql-devel-9.6.10-3.fc27.x86_64
```

However, I cannot find a way to install the `postgresql-*` packages into the chroot environment that contain the updated library headers.

**The Ask**

Since `postgresql` SRPM is supposed to build `postgresql-devel` RPM, I think that `mock` will need to build and install the `postgresql-devel` RPM in the chroot before `rpmbuild` attempts to compile `psql/command.c` so that the latter compilation finds the appropriate library headers (unless the build process is intelligent enough to identify new libraries currently under build).

How can I best accomplish this (would prefer to avoid multiple `mock` calls for each RPM package built from the SRPM unless that's the only way to go)?

Please note that the build process on my system spawns multiple processes to parallel compilations.

I have also tried to use `mockchain —recurse` without success.

**System Info**

```
Linux 4.16.6-202.fc27.x86_64
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly is wrong here, but building PostgreSQL works without PostgreSQL being installed.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Completely agree - I’m not quite certain why mock is pulling in the `postgresql-*` packages to perform the build...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hint, you use the latest `postgresql.spec` version, but you try to build it against rather old (in fact unsupported nowadays) version 27 of Fedora distribution.  I'd encourage you to migrate to a newer version of Fedora, or at least checkout the branch `f27` in the same RPM git repository.

Second hint, we changed the layout of PostgreSQL packaging in Fedora 30+.  We've cut out the library (libpq.so) into separate package, per [announcement](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/U3XR5EGU2TPI2CDHBRBUD4M4LK5OHKU3/).

How to continue; always checkout appropriate branch based on what Fedora you build against, and adjust the spec file appropriately (checkout `f27` and update to PostgreSQL 11.1 in this case).

JFTR (might help), there already is a **testing** modular build of PostgreSQL 11 against Fedora 28+, and the build scripts are maintained in separate [branch](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/postgresql/tree/stream-postgresql-11) `stream-postgresql-11`.  With a bit of luck, you would be able to build that branch against old Fedora 27, too.  Note that this version of `postgresql.spec` file is a little bit complicated (it needs to be because we build it against different versions of Fedora).

Comment: Thank you Pavel (and time passed me by — definitely need to update to `f29`). It’ll take me some time to go through the server update, but will come back after running through the hints. Appreciate the time on this!

Comment: Took time over the weekend to update to `f29`. Everything works as expected. Thank you. For benefit of others, official Fedora RPM build questions can be directed to `Fedora Ask` or freenode `#fedora-devel`